# elementary algebra exercise for 10th grade

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let f be a function: $$f:(3,243)\mapsto \mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=\log_{3}^{2}x(\log_{3}^{2}x+16\log_{3}\frac{81}{x} )$$ Find out the set of values of the function and study the function's injection.
Solution:
$$x \in (3,243)$$ so we don't need to specify. 
f is injective $$\Leftrightarrow \quad \forall \quad x_{1},\quad x_{2} \in (3,\quad 243),\quad f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})\quad \Rightarrow \quad x_{1}=x_{2}$$ so for our function: 
$$\log_{3}^{2}x_{1}(\log_{3}^{2}x_{1}+16\log_{3}\frac{81}{x_{1}})=\log_{3}^{2}x_{2}(\log_{3}^{2}x_{2}+16\log_{3}\frac{81}{x_{2}} )$$ How further? I think I have to use the the properties of the log function.

Comment: Use $\log(81/x)=\log(81)-\log(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Okay $$f(x)=\log_3^2 x(\log_3^2 x+16\log_3 81-16\log_3 x)=\log_3^2 x(\log_3^2 x-16\log_3 x+64)\\\log_3 x=t,t\in(1,5)\\f(x)=t^2(t^2-16t+64)=t^2(t-8)^2\\f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$$$t_1^2(t_1-8)^2=t_2(t_2-8)^2\tag{1}\\t_1(t_1-8)=t_2(t_2-8)\\(t_1-t_2)(t_1+t_2)=8(t_1-t_2)\\t_1+t_2=8$$
(1) is true cause $t>0$.

For example $t_1=3.5,t_2=4.5$ or $x_1=3^{3.5},x_2=3^{4.5}$ so it's not injective

To find the range first find its max by deriving this $t^2(t-8)^2$ and for the lower bound you can see that at $t=1$ the value is $49$ you can check that $t^2(t-8)^2> 49$ which transforms into $t(t-8)<-7$ or $t^2-8t+7<0$ and solution to that is $t\in(1,7)$ hence the range is from $(49,256]$

Answer (score 0):

We have after easy calculation $$f(x)=(\log_3(x))^2(\log_3(x)-8)^2$$ whose domain is obviously $(0,\infty)$.

Taking the derivative one has $$f^{\space '}(x)=\frac{-\ln(\frac{x}{81})\ln(x)(8\ln(3)-\ln(x))}{x(\ln(3))^4}$$ (*where $\log_3(x)=\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(3)}$ of course*).

This derivative takes clearly values zero at the points $x=81$, $x=3^8=6561$ and $x=1$ so we have two minimums at $x=1$ and $x=6561$ and a maximum at $x=81$.

Furthermore $f$ is clearly positive because a square of a real and tends to infinity when $x$ tends to infinity (*not necessary to add that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$*). Since $f(1)=0$ the asked set of values is $[0,\infty)$ and because of having two minimums the function is not injective.